# Make request[] to auto generated list item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, request

I was wondering, how would I go about making a request to a auto generated list of `<input type="checkbox">`.

The code I have so far is this:

```
@{
    if(Request["btn"] == "update")
    {
        // make a list with the checked items
    }
}
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        @{
            string tempChecked = "";

            foreach(Roles r in Roles.getAll(con))
            {
                if(Users.doesUserHaveRole(con,r.name,user._id))
                {
                    tempChecked = "checked";
                }

                    <input type="checkbox" name="@r._id" @tempChecked >@r.name
                    <br />

                    tempChecked = "";
                }
            }
        <input type="submit" value="update" name="btn" />
    </form>
</div>
```

How would I go about doing this, when I can't make a `Request["whatever number it has"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close use

```
Request.Form[list name].ToString()
```

This will give you a list of checked check boxes.  Something like 1,2,5, etc. Hopefully this helps

Edit:
I believe this comes back as null if nothing has been checked.  You can put the result into an array using the split function.  something like this

```
try{
    foreach(var temp in Request.Form[List Name].ToString().Split(',')){
        //this will then iterate over every check box that has been checked and you can save to the database or do something else with them.
    }
}catch{
    //No items were checked
}
```

Comment: How would I then go about checking if one or more is "checked"?

Comment: I believe it comes back null if nothing has been checked.  if you wanted to foreach the list after the null check you can do a .split(',') on it and do something from there